# Use of parallelism — when should "of" and "the" be omitted?

Tags: parallelism

1. I want three notepads of the same size and of different colors.
2. I want three notepads of the same size and different colors.
3. I want three notepads of the same color and size.
4. I want three notepads of the same size and of the different colors.

Which one or ones are correct?

Comment: Number 3 doesn't mean the same thing as the rest of them (same size and same colour, rather than same size and different colour). "Notepads" is not spelled correctly in 1 and 2.

Comment: Are these correct?Though number 3 has not same meaning, is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are correct (grammatically), but you would usually use "but" instead of "and" in such sentences, since there are opposite adjectives being used ("same" and "different").

3 would also be correct but with a different meaning.

4 is definitely not correct. You would not use "the" before "different colors".

Comment: Right. _Different_ is indefinite, since all it means is 'not the same', and that can be in any dimension, so there are many possibilities. Hence no _the_ (which is for definite noun phrases only) before _different colors_,